# Int is not convertible to DictionaryIndex<String, String>

Tags: ios, swift

Hi guys I am in big trouble. Here is my code:

```
let listOfQuestionsAndAnswers = ["Who’s Paul?": "An American", "Who’s Joao?": "A Bresilian", "Who’s Riccardo?": "An Italian"]

@IBAction func answerButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject){

    for (Question, rightAnswer) in listOfQuestionsAndAnswers {

        questionField.text = listOfQuestionsAndAnswers[currentQuestionIndex]
           if currentQuestionIndex <= listOfQuestionsAndAnswers.count
             {
              currentQuestionIndex = (++currentQuestionIndex) % listOfQuestionsAndAnswers.count
              answerBut.setTitle("ANSWER", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
             }
           else
           {
            (sender as UIButton).userInteractionEnabled = false
           }
```

I am getting the error Int is not convertible to DictionaryIndex and I don't understand what that means. Shouldn't I be able to access my dictionary by index.

Comment: `currentQuestionIndex` is of _type_ `Int`, and you try to access the `[String, String]` dictionary using this `Int` as a _key_, but the dictionary expects keys of type `String`. (`questionField.text = listOfQuestionsAndAnswers[currentQuestionIndex]` <-- dictionary `listOfQuestionsAndAnswers ` expects `currentQuestionIndex` to be of type `String` here).

Comment: @Daniel Thanks Daniel

Comment: @dfri How can I do that?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to iterate over the contents of a dictionary, possibly mistaking it for an array of tuples. You could use `dictionary.startIndex`, and then advance to the next index by calling `index.successor()` until `index.successor() == dictionary.endIndex', upon which the index is invalid. I believe a dictionary you can still access by an index similar to an array, however the index of a dictionary is different a type to that of an array.

Comment: @Mrwerdo You understood! Exactly what I'm trying to do. Please help.

Comment: @TanguyMP no problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Int is not convertible to Dictionary<string, string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638608/int-is-not-convertible-to-dictionarystring-string)

Comment: I updated my answer with something that should help.

Answer (score 0):

hard to say, what are you trying to do. here is an example, how to access dictionary (unordered collection of key, value pairs) by different ways

```
let dict = ["a":"A","b":"B"]
for (k,v) in dict {
    print(k,v)
}
/*
b B
a A
*/

dict.forEach { (d) -> () in
    print(d.0,d.1)
}
/*
b B
a A
*/

dict.enumerate().forEach { (e) -> () in
    print(e.index,e.element,e.element.0,e.element.1)
}
/*
0 ("b", "B") b B
1 ("a", "A") a A
*/

dict.indices.forEach { (di) -> () in
    print(dict[di],dict[di].0,dict[di].1)
}
/*
("b", "B") b B
("a", "A") a A
*/

dict.keys.forEach { (k) -> () in
    print(k,dict[k])
}
/*
b Optional("B")
a Optional("A")
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple of things that are going on here that my not be in the way you want them. First your main question you are trying to iterate this dictionary like it is a list ie `let list = [apple, banana, orange]` this list has an `index` that you could iterate through similarly to what you are doing.

```
for fruit in list {
    print(fruit)
 }

 This would print:
 apple
 banana
 orange
```

Where as dictionarys are more `key:value` based.

```
 struct food {
     catigory:String()
     type:String()
 }
```

What I would suggest is that you make a list of dictionary but structure you data a little differently more like

```
 let listOfQuestionAnswers = 
   [["question":"Who’s Paul?","answer":"An American"], 
   ["question":"Who’s Joao?","answer":"A Bresilian"],
   ["question":"Who’s Riccardo?","answer": "An Italian"]]
```

so this lets you have a list of dictionary each dictionary has two keys (question and answer) and now you can iterate through all of them and you questions and answers will be paired together.

or alternatively you could make a `struct` to represent your question answer combo then have a list of those structs. This makes things nice because you can use `dot`syntax to access the items within the struct

```
 struct dictionaryStruct {
    var question:String
    var answer:String
 }

var listOfQuestionAnswers = [dictionaryStruct]()

func makeList(quest:String,answer:String){
    let dict = dictionaryStruct.init(question: quest, answer: answer)
    listOfQuestionAnswers.append(dict)
}

makeList("Who’s Paul?", answer: "An American")
makeList("Who’s Joao?", answer: "A Bresilian")
makeList("Who’s Riccardo?", answer: "An Italian")

for entry in listOfQuestionAnswers {
    print("\(entry.question), \(entry.answer)")
}    


---------- Console Output:
      Who’s Paul?, An American
      Who’s Joao?, A Bresilian
      Who’s Riccardo?, An Italian
```

let me know if you have any other questions?

To solve your score logic you have two lists. The user selects an answer and you already know the index of the question so you just need to check that their answer is the same as the answer for the question at the same index. so look kinda like this

```
if answer == listOfAnswers[currentQuestionIndex]{
    score ++
}
```

Comment: I found another way but when I write the wrong answer it increases my score, but it is not supposed to (it must increase my score -++score- when I write a right answer only

Comment: Is your code updated in the question or is that your original code.

Comment: let listOfQuestions  = ["Who’s Paul", "Who’s Joao, "Who’s Riccardo?"]

let listOfAnswers = ["An American", "A Bresilian", "An Italian"]

@IBAction func answerButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject){
var question = questionField.text


questionField.text = listOfQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]
            if currentQuestionIndex <= listOfQuestions.count
                 {
                  currentQuestionIndex = (++currentQuestionIndex) % listOfQuestions.count
                  answerBut.setTitle("ANSWER", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                  discussQuestion(answer)
                 }

Comment: else
                  {
                (sender as UIButton).userInteractionEnabled = false
                  }


func discussQuestion(answer: String){
        
         for answers in rightAnswers {
            
 
                // right answer
        if (answer  == answers  || answer  == answers  
          || answer  == answers  || answer  == answers )
            {

Comment: alertMessage("Right Answer")
                scoreField.text = "\(++score)"
            }
                
      }
        
    }

Comment: no problem you can actually just edit your question and then past it there that way it formats the code and things. But I have what I need to look at. Give me sec and Ill see where your logic is.

Comment: Ok...There are a lot of informations. Let me have a look on that carefully. Will reply later

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are correct, and I particularly like Daniel Leonard's answer, as it provides a good way to organize your questions and answers.

---

First of all, I would like say that `listOfQuestionsAndAnswers` is not a list - it's actually a Dictionary. In particular, it is a `Dictionary<String, String>`, i.e. it's key must be a string, and it's value must be a string.

But not to worry! The `Dictionary` type conforms to the protocol `CollectionType`, which means that we can use 'traditional' means to index it. It does **not** mean we can access it with an `Int`. But we **can** access it with an index of type `Dictionary.Index`.

***How is that done?***

1. Grab the index from the dictionary.
2. Iterate over the contents, by using the index to grab the values.
3. Get the next index by calling `index.successor()`
4. Check that the index is not invalid, by checking that it is **not** equal to the end index.

***Code***

```
// Not a list of questions, it's a dictionary.
let questionsAndAnswers = ["Who’s Paul?": "An American", 
                           "Who’s Joao?": "A Bresilian", 
                           "Who’s Riccardo?": "An Italian"]

var index = questionsAndAnswers.startIndex
while index != questionsAndAnswers.endIndex {
    let question = questionsAndAnswers[index].0
    let answer = questionsAndAnswers[index].1
    print("Question: \(question); Answer: \(answer)")
    index = index.successor()
}
```

You can see that when we access the contents of the dictionary using an index, we retrieve a tuple. `.0` is the key, and `.1` is the value, in this case, corresponding to the question and answer respectively.

Note: Indexes from a dictionary are not guaranteed to be ordered - they could come out in a different order every time! If you want an ordered collection, then you should use an array.