# Int is not convertible to Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

There is an error at this line (questionField.text = listOfQuestionsAndAnswers[currentQuestionIndex]) (Int is not convertible to Dictionary).
Moreover, I want all the questions to be displayed one-by-one, and after the last question, "Who's is Paul" should be displayed again...

```
let listOfQuestionsAndAnswers = ["Who’s Paul?": "An American", "Who’s Joao?": "A Bresilian", "Who’s Riccardo?": "An Italian"]

@IBAction func answerButtonTapped (sender: AnyObject){

    for (Question, rightAnswer) in listOfQuestionsAndAnswers {

        questionField.text = listOfQuestionsAndAnswers[currentQuestionIndex]
        if currentQuestionIndex <= listOfQuestionsAndAnswers.count
        {
            currentQuestionIndex = (++currentQuestionIndex) % listOfQuestionsAndAnswers.count
            answerBut.setTitle("ANSWER", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        else
        {
            (sender as UIButton).userInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error Int is not convertible to DictionaryIndex and I don't understand what that means. Shouldn't I be able to access my dictionary by index.

Comment: On which line does the error happen?

Comment: Your `currentQuestionIndex` has a type of `Int` and your `listOfQuestionsAndAnswers` has a type of `Dictionary<String:String>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't subscript a dictionary by `Int`.  Dictionaries contain keys and values and are subscripted by the key.  In this case your `listOfQuestionsAndAnswers` is a Dictionary where the keys and values are both Strings.

If you wanted to subscript by Int, consider using an array of `(String, String)` tuples.

If you want to use a dictionary, you have to retrieve the value from the dictionary by its key:

```
listOfQuestionsAndAnswers["Who’s Paul?"] // "An American"
```

Answer (score 0):

listOfQuestionsAndAnswers is not an array is a Dictionary and listOfQuestionsAndAnswers[someIntIndex] is not working because your keys are strings

```
    let listOfQuestionsAndAnswers = ["Who’s Paul?": "An American", "Who’s Joao?": "A Bresilian", "Who’s Riccardo?": "An Italian"]

    @IBAction func answerButtonTapped (sender: AnyObject){

        for (Question, rightAnswer) in listOfQuestionsAndAnswers {

            //questionField.text = listOfQuestionsAndAnswers[currentQuestionIndex] 
//changed to this
questionField.text = Quesition
            if currentQuestionIndex <= listOfQuestionsAndAnswers.count
            {
                currentQuestionIndex = (++currentQuestionIndex) % listOfQuestionsAndAnswers.count
                answerBut.setTitle("ANSWER", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
            else
            {
                (sender as UIButton).userInteractionEnabled = false
            }
        } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your listOfQuestionsAndAnswers is a dictionary of type `Dictionary<String:String>`. You can't index into a dictionary with string keys using an integer index like that line.

Your for loop is fetching each key/value pair into a tuple, which is fine, but dictionaries do not have a numeric index. In fact, dictionaries are completely unordered. If you want to have a group of questions and answers that you can loop through, use an index to fetch a specific question/answer pair using an index, etc, you should consider an array of tuples, or an array of question/answer structs, or some other data structure.